# SCM (SVN) Issue With Added Folders

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, svn, version-control

I'm new with Xcode SCM tool. I would like to ask one question to you guys in detail.

We (Guy-A and Guy-B) working on the same SVN repository project through Xcode SCM tool.

We checked out the code and Guy-A added a folder to the project as **SampleFileAdded** to his local mapped version  (please refer Figure1) and he added & committed to the SVN repository fine.

After that Guy-B updated / got latest version from SVN .

Here is the issue.Guy-B's project local mapped folder now contains the latest folder that Guy-A is added. However it didn't link with his Xcode folder structure.Guy-B need to drag the folder to his Xcode to link it with project.

May I know how can I avoid this step. Any help on this is appreciated.

Figure1:
[image]

**Guy-A Local Machine**

[image]

[image]

**Guy-B Local Machine After Updated**

[image]

[image]

Comment: where is Figure1 to refer?

Answer (score 1):

On adding the folder to the project the project file will have been modified. It looks like somehow this was not committed, hence the problem.

Did you use `File > Source Control > Commit…` or select the (apparently) modified set of files and commit those? The former method will catch everything - sometimes Xcode fails to mark files as modified in the project window, and sometimes you'll even notice the count of files in the commit dialog is greater than the number listed in the dialog...

`File > Source Control > Commit…` should catch everything, even if it is not immediately apparent that it has. (Use an svn client, such as svnX, or `svn` in a terminal window to determine exactly what was/needs to be committed.)

Answer (score 0):

Have Guy-A committed the project file too ? that is `.xcodeproj` . Please try to commit project file too then you need not to drag the folder after update.

Comment: .xcodeproj file is initially committed. when Guy-A is added a new folder, SCM will show only one item to commit. It doesn't display .xcodeproj is updated/need to commit.